# Bigcommerce stencil inconsistent CSS styles between development and production

Tags: bigcommerce

Is Bigcommerce performing some sort of minification to the main `theme.css` stylesheet being generated in production? I'm seeing a strange issue where certain styles that work correctly in development do appear in production.

Here's an example. In my development store, you can see the new customer sign-up box here:

[image]

As you can see on the right, I'm showing the styles that are being applied to the `ul` element, which ensures there is a left margin of 1.25rem.

Now, after bundling the theme with `stencil bundle` and uploading it to my development store, this is what I see:

[image]

As you can see, the `ul` element no longer has it's `margin-left` applied. On the right, you can see that the styles being applied are not the same as they were in production. Specifically, the `margin-left: 1.25rem` rule is being overriden by the `margin: 0` rule.

It's as if some process was run to combine style declarations for certain elements, but this caused the order of the rules to change. Does anyone know what is happening here? Or what process is being used to attempt to minify this css? Maybe it's a bug with the library doing the minification.

**UPDATE**

Here's another example of the issue that I just came across. I have a style declared to show a magnify glass when the user hovers over the main image to indicate that they can zoom. The style is defined as follows:

```
.zoomImg {
    cursor: -webkit-zoom-in;
    cursor: -moz-zoom-in;
}
```

As you can see, in development, this style appears correctly for `.zoomImg`:

[image]

However, in production the style is incorrect. The chrome prefixed declaration is missing:

[image]

Where did it go? I'm confused why the styles are being changed. Again, I'm assuming it's part of some minification process. Any ideas?

Comment: Please see update. I added another example of what appears to be the same issue.

Comment: Is this on the checkout page?

Comment: No it is not on or specific to the checkout page

Comment: It looks like a mismatch between autoprefixer and we need to investigate that it is being run on the bundle process.

Comment: @Alyss - interesting, but I'm confused why autoprefixer would effect styles like `margin`, as described in my first example. Any idea?

Comment: @Alyss I was able to fix the issue with `zoom` by simply changing the styles to not use browser prefixes. So just `.zoomImg { cursor: zoom-in; }`. According to caniuse the prefixes shouldn't be needed anymore. I guess that was throwing off autoprefixer. I still have the `margin` issue that is mentioned in my first example. I'm not sure why that is happening. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @Alyss any idea what's going on with this? I'm trying to work around it for now but it's really becoming a huge hassle trying to adjust my css just to work around a bug. Any update?

Comment: I was communicating on behalf of an engineer who doesn't have the appropriate rep to comment. He informed me he is investigating but I have received no update.

Comment: @Alyss - any more updates on this? Would love to see this resolved so I can stop worrying about workarounds with every theme update.

Comment: @Alyss - any word?

Comment: @flyingL123 No, I haven't heard anything. The engineer who was investigating has since moved on to another opportunity outside of BC.

Comment: @Alyss can you get it picked up by someone else? What should I do to get this fixed?

Comment: It sounds like you currently have a workaround and our team is working to ensure bug fixes and feature rollouts.